# Second FileServer serves html but not images

Tags: http, go, static, mux

I'm running into the following problem with Go and `gorilla/mux` routers when building a simple API. I'm sure it's the usual stupid mistake that is right on my face, but I can't see it.

#### Simplified project structure

```
|--main.go
|
|--public/--index.html
|        |--image.png
|
|--img/--img1.jpg
|     |--img2.jpg
|     |--...
|...
```

#### `main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var Router = mux.NewRouter()

func InitRouter() {
    customers := Router.PathPrefix("/customers").Subrouter()

    customers.HandleFunc("/all", getAllCustomers).Methods("GET")
    customers.HandleFunc("/{customerId}", getCustomer).Methods("GET")
    // ...
    // Registering whatever middleware
    customers.Use(middlewareFunc)

    users := Router.PathPrefix("/users").Subrouter()

    users.HandleFunc("/register", registerUser).Methods("POST")
    users.HandleFunc("/login", loginUser).Methods("POST")
    // ...

    // Static files (customer pictures)
    var dir string
    flag.StringVar(&dir, "images", "./img/", "Directory to serve the images")
    Router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))))

    var publicDir string
    flag.StringVar(&publicDir, "public", "./public/", "Directory to serve the homepage")
    Router.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(publicDir))))
}

func main() {
    InitRouter()
    // Other omitted configuration
    server := &http.Server{
        Handler: Router,
        Addr:    ":" + port,
        // Adding timeouts
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    // ...
}
```

Subroutes work OK, with middleware and all. The images under `img` are correctly served if I go to `localhost:5000/static/img1.png`.

The thing is, going to `localhost:5000` serves the `index.html` that resides in `public`, but then `localhost:5000/image.png` is a `404 not found` instead.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
// handles '/' and *ONLY* '/'
Router.Handle("/",
        http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(publicDir))))
```

To this:

```
// handles '/' and all sub-routes
Router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(
        http.StripPrefix("/",http.FileServer(http.Dir(publicPath))))
```

---

Basically, in your original code, the router for `/` is handling this path and only that path (no sub-routes).

You may wonder why your original code "worked" for at least one file (`index.html`). The reason is the `http.FileServer` given a path that is a directory - not a file - will default to serving the index page file `index.html` (see `FileServer` [source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go#L546)).

Using `PathPrefix` allows the (fileserver) handler to accept *all* URL paths below the path `/`.

Comment: It works, thanks! One more question. I assume I'd need to take into account the order in which I declare the sub-routers, as happens with Go's `net/http`, right? Would the routes mess up if I moved the corrected statement up, right before the other sub-router initialisations?

Comment: I don't use gorilla mux - but it does look like the order of registration is important (with first registration match winning). This is NOT the case with net/http -from the [ServeMux docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) _Longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree._

Comment: Alright, thanks! I had read about that a few weeks ago and wrongly related it to statement order in my comment. I stand corrected! Now if I could just edit the above comment to avoid confusing others... :/